# Move cursor up/down one line in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using Atom with soft wrap turned on. In most simple editors such as gedit, Ctrl-Down would be used to skip ahead to the true next line, ignoring any wrapped lines below (same as j and k in Vim).

However in Atom this shortcut produces the result of moving the line itself around, which is less useful to me. I'd like to remap Ctrl-Up and Ctrl-Down to move the cursor up or down to the next true line, as described above.

I'm familiar with editing my keymap file, but I simply can't find any command that would be the equivalent of moving ahead one full line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom command in your `init.coffee` like this:

```
atom.workspaceView.command 'custom:move-next-buffer-line', ->
  editor = atom.workspace.getActiveEditor()
  editor.moveCursorToEndOfLine()
  editor.moveCursorRight()
```

And then just reverse it for moving to the previous buffer line. You can then map the custom command in your keymap, which you said you're familiar with.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately I've already moved back to Vim from frustration, so I probably won't test this. I hope your answer will help other users though.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the *vim-mode-plus* package, then just modify your `keymap.cson` file by adding

```
# except insert
# -------------------------
'atom-text-editor.vim-mode-plus:not(.insert-mode)':
  # Motions
  # -------------------------
  'k': 'vim-mode-plus:move-up-screen'
  'j': 'vim-mode-plus:move-down-screen'
```

See for details https://github.com/t9md/atom-vim-mode-plus/blob/master/keymaps/vim-mode-plus.cson

Comment: Great answer! :)

For anyone else who winds up here from Google search; I wanted to do something similar: make `j` and `k` move _within_ soft wrapped lines, unlike the default vim behavior. Based on this answer, I made this change:
```
'atom-text-editor.vim-mode-plus:not(.insert-mode)':
  'k': 'core:move-up'     # Allow j and k to move within a soft-wrapped line,
  'j': 'core:move-down'   # whereas up and down arrows move hard buffer lines.
```
Thanks! :)

Comment: Oh, nvm, i didn't understand that `move-up-screen` is already EXACTLY what I wanted.  haha so this answer is _exactly_ what i wanted. thanks much! :)